# A certain adaptive card crashes my webchat

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm currently working on making some dynamically generated cards, but for some reason when I try to add this one as an adaptive card the whole webchat crashes.

I've tried passing the JSON as an object without double quotes, as a string with double quotes, and as an object with double quotes.

```
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "id": "header",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "id": "headerColSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "actionTextCol",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "id": "actionText",
                  "text": "Action Here!",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "Right"
                }
              ],
              "width": "stretch"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "actionTextCol",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "id": "actionText",
                  "text": "Action Here!",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "Right"
                }
              ],
              "width": "stretch"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "id": "columnSet1",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "id": "columnIndex0",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "textOne1",
              "text": "Test text One"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "id": "columnIndex0",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "textTwo1",
              "text": "Sec Text One"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "id": "columnSet2",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "id": "columnIndex1",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "textOne2",
              "text": "Test text 2"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "id": "columnIndex1",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "id": "textTwo2",
              "text": "Sec Text 2"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "id": "footer",
      "items": [],
      "separator": true
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
    }
```

This JSON should be able to be attached to an adaptive card in the web chat, but instead the whole screen goes white and throws these errors

card-elements.js:2330 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalValidateProperties' of null

index.js:1375 uncaught at observeActivity TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalValidateProperties' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of things wrong with your Adaptive Card, most notably `ColumnSet` is supposed to have an array of objects with the `type` property set to `Column`. Also, `TextBlocks` do not have an `items` attribute. I would highly recommend that you use the [Adaptive Card Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to create your cards. Also take a look at the [Adaptive Card Schema Explorer](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/).

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "id": "header",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "New TextBlock"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The designer doesn't validate the json.  It would be nice if it did.  (So the key word here is "create" the card with the designer.)

Comment: For future reference, I also had a similar crash later on while using the javaScript SDK and found the fix was swapping my horizontal and vertical alignment calls from just "Left" or "Right" to Adaptive.VerticalAlignment.Left or Right like so
```YourContainerOrObject.verticalContentAlignment = Adaptive.VerticalAlignment.Center```